# dockerでpostgresのコンテナを建てた際にdocker-entrypoint-initdb.dが実行されない。

Tags: docker, postgresql, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

フォルダー構成は下記のようになっております。

```
docker-compose.yml
backend - sql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00-neumann-init.sql
```

docker-compose.ymlの中身

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: neumann
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: neumann_development
      TZ: Asia/Tokyo
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    # stopでコンテナを落とすならDBのデータは消えないそうなのであえて永続化しない
    volumes:
        - ./backend/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

00-neumann-init.sqlの中身

```
create user neumann2;
create database neumann_development2;
alter role neumann2 with Superuser;
```

これで `docker-compose up --build` を実行しても下記のようなログが出力されてsqlが上手く実行されないです。

`/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

ログ全体

```
Creating neumann_db_1 ... done
Attaching to neumann_db_1
db_1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db_1  | This user must also own the server process.
db_1  | 
db_1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db_1  | 
db_1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
db_1  | 
db_1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db_1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
db_1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db_1  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db_1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db_1  | selecting default time zone ... Asia/Tokyo
db_1  | creating configuration files ... ok
db_1  | running bootstrap script ... ok
db_1  | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db_1  | syncing data to disk ... initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1  | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1  | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1  | ok
db_1  | 
db_1  | 
db_1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1  | 
db_1  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1  | 
db_1  | waiting for server to start....2022-06-04 13:45:32.867 JST [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.3 (Debian 14.3-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:32.870 JST [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:32.879 JST [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-06-04 13:45:32 JST
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:32.886 JST [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1  |  done
db_1  | server started
db_1  | CREATE DATABASE
db_1  | 
db_1  | 
db_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
db_1  | 
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:33.259 JST [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1  | waiting for server to shut down....2022-06-04 13:45:33.262 JST [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:33.268 JST [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:33.269 JST [50] LOG:  shutting down
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:33.291 JST [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1  |  done
db_1  | server stopped
db_1  | 
db_1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1  | 
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:33.388 JST [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.3 (Debian 14.3-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:33.389 JST [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:33.389 JST [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:33.393 JST [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:33.399 JST [62] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-06-04 13:45:33 JST
db_1  | 2022-06-04 13:45:33.408 JST [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Killing neumann_db_1  ... done
ERROR: 2
```

他に必要な情報があればコメント頂ければと思います。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ホスト側で `sql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` のように `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` のサブディレクトリまで作成しているのが余計な気がします。

以下の通りボリュームマウントの直下に配置するとどうでしょうか。

```
backend - sql/00-neumann-init.sql
```

Comment: 上手く行きました！ありがとうございます。